# Wrap matches shown by You Complete Me

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, wrapping

Is it possible to wrap the matches shown by YCM ? My current workaround is to decrease font size till I am able to see it and then increase font size. This is tedious and painful.

Is there any other way?

Comment: YCM uses the standard completion engine of vim. Hard to believe that the lines can be broken. The way it is displayed depends on the vim gui more, I think. You can try Oni for example. But mostly it will be the same.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what is Oni? Is it a vim plugin?

Comment: No, it is a gui for neovim. Not recommended in general as it is not maintained

Comment: @eyalkarni So are you saying that there is no solution to wrapping lines in autocompletion matches menu in vim using Youcompleteme ?

Comment: I am saying there couldn't be one. But perhaps another window could appear with the full name (thinking about documentation) . Perhaps the size is adjustable.